# .each() is stopping after one interation?

Tags: jquery, each

Such an easy question but I can't figure it out...

```
function pageLoad() {
    runDatepickers();
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $('span[id^="rfv"]').css("display", "block");
        alert("Submit was clicked");
        $('span[id^="rfv"]').each(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            if ($(this).css("display") = "inline") {
                alert("display is inline");
                $(this).css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    });
};
```

This stops after one iteration, I've got multiple spans on the page that start with "rfv", the first statement `$('span[id^="rfv"]').css("display", "block");` does correctly select and change the display of all those elements, yet according to my alerts, when I get into the each, it only matches the first element, and that is it. What am I missing here??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Correctness:** change

```
if ($(this).css("display") = "inline")
```

to

```
if ($(this).css("display") === "inline")
```

**Performance:** cache jQuery selectors where appropriate.

**Conciseness**: take advantage of the fact that [`.css()` can take a function](http://api.jquery.com/css#css2) as the second argument.

---

```
function pageLoad() {
    runDatepickers();
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $('span[id^="rfv"]').css("display", function (i, display) {
            return display === "inline" ? "block" : display;
        });
    });
};
```

---

**Epilogue:** please, oh *please* don't use `alert()` for debugging. Use a real debugger.

Comment: @Matt Ball most helpful in general, tons of great stuff, I don't use jquery/js much so I am not well verse at it, which "real debugger" would you recommend?

Comment: WebKit: it's built in. Firefox: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). IE: save yourself the agony, and hang yourself now, or switch to another browser.

Comment: @Matt Ball, oh also you can remove that line you ask the question about, I just wrote that to make sure my selector was actually working.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($(this).css("display") = "inline") {
```

Change the `=` to a `===`

`=` is an assignment operator where as `===` is a non-converting equality operator